# TIdHMACSHA256.TIdHMACSHA384.TIdHMACSHA512 do not work in Delphi

Tags: delphi, indy

Why HashValue function of TIdHMACSHA256+ (Indy/delphi) always return empty? For example, the code below does not work.

```
var
  Hash: TIdHMACSHA256 ;
  HashValue: TBytes;
begin
  SetCurrentDir(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)));
  Hash := TIdHMACSHA256 .Create;
  try
    Hash.Key := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes('devaee2');
    HashValue := Hash.HashValue(TFile.ReadAllBytes('menu.xml'));
    // HashValue is an empty array, why?
    Tag := Length(HashValue);
    TFile.WriteAllBytes('menu.xml.hash', HashValue);

  finally
    FreeAndNil(Hash);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickly looking at Indy 10 sources, they don't have coded SHA256-512r hashes, and use some kind of system hashes (??).
Please check TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable - most likely it will return false.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you have not successfully loaded the OpenSSL libraries that are needed to implement the hash. Call `IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary`. You'll also need to make sure that your program can find suitable OpenSSL DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Look for component TDCP (try https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/dcpcrypt2010). The source is complete. Works fine on Rad Studio 2007 ... XE5
Native from Delphi, you have SHA1 but no SHA2 and others ( I think because law, or I don't know...)